# Why do I get the error "cannot find -lcurl" when trying to compile example code?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to follow this curl example and get it to compile:

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/smtp-mail.c

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/Makefile.example

And what I have so far is borderline copy/pasted, but I keep getting an error "cannot find -lcurl"

This is what I have for the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "curl-7.64.0/include/curl/curl.h"

/*
 * For an SMTP example using the multi interface please see smtp-multi.c.
 */ 

/* The libcurl options want plain addresses, the viewable headers in the mail
 * can very well get a full name as well.
 */ 
#define FROM_ADDR    "<sender@example.org>"
#define TO_ADDR      "<addressee@example.net>"
#define CC_ADDR      "<info@example.org>"

#define FROM_MAIL "Sender Person " FROM_ADDR
#define TO_MAIL   "A Receiver " TO_ADDR
#define CC_MAIL   "John CC Smith " CC_ADDR

static const char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " TO_MAIL "\r\n",
  "From: " FROM_MAIL "\r\n",
  "Cc: " CC_MAIL "\r\n",
  "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
  "rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
  "Subject: SMTP example message\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */ 
  "The body of the message starts here.\r\n",
  "\r\n",
  "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
  "Check RFC5322.\r\n",
  NULL
};

struct upload_status {
  int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
  struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
  const char *data;

  if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
    return 0;
  }

  data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

  if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->lines_read++;

    return len;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
  struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
  struct upload_status upload_ctx;

  upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* This is the URL for your mailserver */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://mail.example.com");

    /* Note that this option isn't strictly required, omitting it will result
     * in libcurl sending the MAIL FROM command with empty sender data. All
     * autoresponses should have an empty reverse-path, and should be directed
     * to the address in the reverse-path which triggered them. Otherwise,
     * they could cause an endless loop. See RFC 5321 Section 4.5.5 for more
     * details.
     */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM_ADDR);

    /* Add two recipients, in this particular case they correspond to the
     * To: and Cc: addressees in the header, but they could be any kind of
     * recipient. */ 
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO_ADDR);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, CC_ADDR);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

    /* We're using a callback function to specify the payload (the headers and
     * body of the message). You could just use the CURLOPT_READDATA option to
     * specify a FILE pointer to read from. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* Send the message */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Free the list of recipients */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

    /* curl won't send the QUIT command until you call cleanup, so you should
     * be able to re-use this connection for additional messages (setting
     * CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM and CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT as required, and calling
     * curl_easy_perform() again. It may not be a good idea to keep the
     * connection open for a very long time though (more than a few minutes
     * may result in the server timing out the connection), and you do want to
     * clean up in the end.
     */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return (int)res;
}
```

And this is what I'm using for the makefile:

```
TARGET = email
OBJS= smtp-mail.o
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -g
LDFLAGS = -L/curl-7.64.0/lib
LIBS = -lcurl -lsocket -lnsl -lssl -lcrypto
$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC)  -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

smtp-mail.o : smtp-mail.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

EDIT: I updated the paths in smtp-mail.c and the makefile:

```
#include "/user/jastei/Email/curl-7.58.0/include/curl/curl.h"

LDFLAGS = -L/user/jastei/Email/curl-7.58.0/lib/ -L/user/jastei/Email/curl-7.58.0/lib/vtls
```

I ran the commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/user/jastei/Email/curl-7.58.0 --disable-shared

make

make install
```

At first, it looked like nothing has changed, however, instead of "cannot find -lcurl" I got this: cannot find -lsocket

EDIT 2: Regarding cmake...when I called cmake:

```
/user/jastei/Email/cmake/bin/cmake CMakeLists.txt
```

I got this error:

```
File /user/jastei/Email/cmake/bin/headers/conf.h.in does not exist.
```

Comment: Do you actually have a directory named `/curl-7.64.0/lib`, and does it contain `libcurl.a`?

Comment: I have a directory named /curl-7.64.0/lib There's libcurl.plist, libcurl.rc, and libcurl.vers.in, but no libcurl.a

Comment: In fact...I did a search through the curl-7.64.0 directory and there is no libcurl.a

Comment: Best advice I have is to build cURL again and see if there are any hints in the build output. Maybe the build choked and died. Maybe it put libcurl.a somewhere weird.

Comment: I downloaded it again. Ran another search. Lots of libcurl files, but no libcurl.a

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: I'm running this in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It sounds like you've downloaded the source tarball. Install libcurl-dev with apt instead since you're on Ubuntu. Swift and easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to build libcurl yourself to get the static library that you want to compile with. You can grab the latest release at https://github.com/curl/curl/releases/tag/curl-7_64_0. Download the source code zip archive. You can view https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html for full building instructions but basically you need to extract the source code, open your terminal, `cd` to the directory that has the `configure` script and the `Makefile`, and then type the following commands:

```
# change the below prefix path to where you want curl to install
# e.g. ~/curl-7.64.0
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/to --disable-shared
make
make install
```

Let it work its magic. That *should* give you the files that you need.